# Why is this jquery pageinit not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me here, why isnt this not working.

```
    $(document).on('pageinit pageshow', function(){
 $(".col-lg-6.md-letter-text").css({ 'height': ($(".col-lg-6.md-letter-img").height() + 'px') });
 $(".col-lg-6.tab-feat-text-col").css({ 'height': ($(".col-md-6.tab-img-col.visible-lg").height() + 'px') });
 $(".prod-tab-col").css({ 'height': ($(".gff-tab-content-col").height() + 'px') });

 $('#gff-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('#myInput').focus()
 $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I'm sorry,I'm new to this. I'm trying to resize those div's when the page loads (website) loads.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing curly bracket and a parenthesis. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("pageinit pageshow", function() {
  $(".col-lg-6.md-letter-text").css({
    height: $(".col-lg-6.md-letter-img").height() + "px"
  });
  $(".col-lg-6.tab-feat-text-col").css({
    height: $(".col-md-6.tab-img-col.visible-lg").height() + "px"
  });
  $(".prod-tab-col").css({
    height: $(".gff-tab-content-col").height() + "px"
  });

  $("#gff-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $("#myInput").focus();
    $(this).removeData("bs.modal");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @dankreiger. but this doesn't seems to work either. the div's aren't resizing. but when I use "window.onresize = function(event) " it works fine. but that's not how I want it to work.

Comment: No problem. I think it would be helpful if you could post your html or make a fiddle/codepen.